# How can a shared library (.so) call a function that is implemented in its loader code?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I have a shared library that I implemented and want the .so to call a function that's implemented in the main program which loads the library.

Let's say I have main.c (executable) which contains:

```
void inmain_function(void*);
dlopen("libmy.so");
```

In the my.c (the code for the libmy.so) I want to call `inmain_function`:

```
inmain_function(NULL);
```

How can the shared library call `inmain_function` regardless the fact `inmain_function` is defined in the main program.

**Note: I want to call a symbol in main.c from my.c not vice versa which is the common usage.**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need make a  register function in your .so so that the executable can give a function pointer to your .so for it's later used.

Like this:

```
void in_main_func () {
// this is the function that need to be called from a .so
}

void (*register_function)(void(*)());
void *handle = dlopen("libmylib.so");

register_function = dlsym(handle, "register_function");

register_function(in_main_func);
```

the register_function needs to store the function pointer in a variable in the .so where the other function in the .so can find it.

Your mylib.c would the need to look something like this:

```
void (*callback)() = NULL;

void register_function( void (*in_main_func)())
{
    callback = in_main_func;
}

void function_needing_callback() 
{
     callback();
}
```

Comment: I'd rather do `if (callback) { callback(); return 0; } else { return -1; }` to indicate an error and to avoid calling `NULL` (which would be fatal).

Comment: Right, removed the fist line.

Answer (score 49):

You have two options, from which you can choose:

**Option 1**: export all symbols from your executable.
This is simple option, just when building executable, add a flag `-Wl,--export-dynamic`. This would make all functions available to library calls.

**Option 2**: create an export symbol file with list of functions, and use `-Wl,--dynamic-list=exported.txt`. This requires some maintenance, but more accurate.

To demonstrate: simple executable and dynamically loaded library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void exported_callback() /*< Function we want to export */
{
    printf("Hello from callback!\n");
}

void unexported_callback() /*< Function we don't want to export */
{
    printf("Hello from unexported callback!\n");
}

typedef void (*lib_func)();

int call_library()
{
   void     *handle  = NULL;
   lib_func  func    = NULL;
   handle = dlopen("./libprog.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
   if (handle == NULL)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open lib: %s\n", dlerror());
       return -1;
   }
   func = dlsym(handle, "library_function");

   if (func == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Unable to get symbol\n");
      return -1;
   }

   func();
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello from main!\n");
    call_library();
    return 0;
}
```

Library code (lib.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int exported_callback();

int library_function()
{
    printf("Hello from library!\n");
    exported_callback();
    /* unexported_callback(); */ /*< This one will not be exported in the second case */
    return 0;
}
```

So, first build the library (this step doesn't differ):

```
 gcc -shared -fPIC lib.c -o libprog.so
```

Now build executable with all symbols exported:

```
 gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic main.c -o prog.exe -ldl
```

Run example:

```
 $ ./prog.exe
 Hello from main!
 Hello from library!
 Hello from callback!
```

Symbols exported:

```
 $ objdump -e prog.exe -T | grep callback
 00000000004009f4 g    DF .text  0000000000000015  Base        exported_callback
 0000000000400a09 g    DF .text  0000000000000015  Base        unexported_callback
```

Now with the exported list (`exported.txt`):

```
{
    extern "C"
    {
       exported_callback;
    };
};
```

Build & check visible symbols:

```
$ gcc -Wl,--dynamic-list=./exported.txt main.c -o prog.exe -ldl
$ objdump -e prog.exe -T | grep callback
0000000000400774 g    DF .text  0000000000000015  Base        exported_callback
```

Comment: when you compile libprog.so like this it will find that exported_callback is a missing symbol.

Comment: ps. to answer my own question: one can disable the "undefined symbol" error and it'll work, eg in clang with `-undefined dynamic_lookup`. on linux with gcc this magically works as described in the post, but i have no idea why.

Comment: This is so much a better answer than the one accepted! I wish it would be on the top.

Answer (score 7):

1. Put your main function's prototype in a .h file and include it in both your main and dynamic library code.
2. With GCC, simply compile your main program with the `-rdynamic` flag.
3. Once loaded, your library will be able to call the function from the main program.

A little further explanation is that once compiled, your dynamic library will have an undefined symbol in it for the function that is in the main code. Upon having your main app load the library, the symbol will be resolved by the main program's symbol table. I've used the above pattern numerous times and it works like a charm.

Comment: Just curious, what happen if another shared lib have the symbol as well?

Comment: The main application's symbol will supersede/override the library's, unless the library's function was defined with the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

**The following can be used to load a dynamic library and call it from the loading call (in case somebody came here after looking for how to load and call a function in an .so library)**:

```
void* func_handle = dlopen ("my.so", RTLD_LAZY); /* open a handle to your library */

void (*ptr)() = dlsym (func_handle, "my_function"); /* get the address of the function you want to call */

ptr(); /* call it */

dlclose (func_handle); /* close the handle */
```

Don't forget to put `#include <dlfcn.h>` and link with the `–ldl` option.

You might also want to add some logic that checks if `NULL` is returned. If it is the case you can call `dlerror` and it should give you some meaningful messages describing the problem.

Other posters have however provided more suitable answers for your problem.

Comment: Yes, this will call a function in your `.so` library from another file (such as your where your main is). Is this what you meant sorry?

Comment: Since others have provided better solutions than I could I wasn't sure if there was anything to add. If you insist I can remove it (thought it could still be useful if someone is looking for loading a dynamic library).

Comment: This post does not actually answer the question OP asked.

Comment: @Dr.JohnnyMohawk That's made fairly obvious by the comments.

Comment: Sure. Just following the instructions StackOverflow provides — vis a vis, explain your down-vote.