# Using __gcov_flush within a library doesn't force the other modules to yield .gcda files

Tags: c++, c, gcc, code-coverage, gcov

Lately I have been trying to use gcc/gcov to undertake code-coverage testing for a C++ project. The project consists of its main module and several .so libraries, which should all be taken into measurement.

I have compiled all the modules with *--coverage* parameter each with gcc and kept them where they were generated, together with corresponding .gcno tag files. After a normal execution and graceful exit the .gcda files could be properly generated.
The problem is, the program is supposed to be a services without interruption or termination, and it's not allowed to insert any customized code (like a signal handler) into the main module. As the solutions from the web suggest, I wrote a signal handler function in a standalone .so library, which invokes *__gcov_flush* on receiving *SIGUSR1* signal to flush the runtime coverage counters to files.

However, it was observed that, while the *__gcov_flush* function is guaranteed to be properly invoked, only the .gcda file of the .so library is generated during runtime. It seems to me that *__gcov_flush* is in charge of flushing the data of the wrapper module but not the others. I wonder if this is how it is supposed to work, or is there some tricks I need to take care of to generate complete results?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here.

- If your executable loads several shared libraries it is quite hard
  to get the functionality needed. The linker adds profiling code from
  `libgcov.a` for every shared library and it is hard to call every
  library's `__gcov_flush()` from one central place like signal handler
  defined in yet another shared library.
- The function `__gcov_flush()` function from `libgcov.a` is declared
  with `__attribute__ ((__visibility__ ("hidden")))`

If you extract _gcov.o from the archive and run

`objdump -t _gcov.o`

you see something like

```
   _gcov.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

   SYMBOL TABLE:
   000014b4 g     F .text  00000016 .hidden __gcov_flush
```

Linker doesn't export hidden symbols even if you ask it to do that
   as it mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081131/how-to-call-a-function-in-the-main-program-from-a-dynamically-loaded-shared-libr) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175802/symbols-from-convenience-library-not-getting-exported-in-executable)

So I see two solutions for the second problem.

1. You may try to edit symbol table for `_gcov.o` in `libgcov.a` and
   set visibility to `"default"` instead of `"hidden"`. I didn't take
   that way because I didn't find any good elf editor.

   If you managed to do that make sure to update your link command so
   it links this patched `_gcov.o` instead of default one from
   `libgcov.a`. Basically, you need to remove `--coverage` option from
   your linker flags for that.
2. You may create a wrapper for `__gcov_flush()` declare and export it
   as it suggested in the links above. Call this wrapper from your
   signal handler in the shared library.

   I suggest you not to add profiling for the small signal handler
   library - it is really unnecessary.