# Linux' dynamique linker : how to call a function from the main process from an .so object?

Tags: c, linux, linker-errors, .so

In my [main source code](https://github.com/destroyedlolo/Selene/blob/master/src/selene.c), I defined a function named findConst(). In the same source, I'm loading a shared object (.so) using **dlopen()** et **dlsym()**.

In this [shared object](https://github.com/destroyedlolo/Selene/blob/master/src/SelPlugins/DirectFB/directfb.c), I have some code that use findConst() ... but unfortunately, when I run my progy, I got a lookup error :

    `./Selene: symbol lookup error: ./SelDirectFB.so: undefined symbol: findConst`

What I need to do to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Needing to do this is almost always an indication of poor design. But if you really must then have a look at [How to call a function in the main program from a dynamically loaded shared librar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081131/how-to-call-a-function-in-the-main-program-from-a-dynamically-loaded-shared-libr)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out this other question I wasn't able to found : -Wl,--export-dynamic makes it working. But do you consider that as a poor design ? The goal is not to create a library shared among several tools, the goal here is to create a plugin dedicated to a particular program. It's only to make DirectFB usage optional, depending on which system my tool is running.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that and if you succeed to do so you shouldn't. Do the opposite, define `findConst()` in the shared object and then load it in the main program with `dlsym()`.

Or even better, link the main program to the shared object and call the function directly.